# How to get the first accessed time file was created along with the last modified time?

Tags: python, date, time

I have a Text file with following dates.

I am able to get the last modified time of the file as given below. Is there any way to get the first accessed time of the file?

```
fileloc = "/test/data1.log"
modifiedTime = os.path.getmtime(fileloc)
print datetime.fromtimestamp(modifiedTime).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

> data :

```
2013-11-21T13:12:09
2013-11-21T13:15:11
2013-11-21T13:15:13
2013-11-21T13:20:09
2013-11-21T14:22:10
2013-11-21T14:22:13
2013-11-21T14:25:09
2013-12-22T13:08:18
2013-12-22T14:09:18
2013-12-22T14:22:18
2013-12-22T14:30:45
```

> expected data :

```
First accessed time : 2013-11-21T13:12:09
last modified time : 2013-12-22T14:30:45
```

Comment: Do it sorted already? Maybe you can get first line and last line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the other family of `os.path.*time` functions:

> `os.path.getatime(path)`
>
> Return the **time of last access** of path. The return value is a number
>   giving the number of seconds since the epoch (see the time module).
>   Raise OSError if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.
>
> If os.stat_float_times() returns True, the result is a floating point
>   number.
>
> `os.path.getmtime(path)`
>   Return the **time of last modification** of path.
>   The return value is a number giving the number of seconds since the
>   epoch (see the time module). Raise OSError if the file does not exist
>   or is inaccessible.
>
> If os.stat_float_times() returns True, the result is a floating point
>   number.
>
> os.path.getctime(path)
>   Return the system’s ctime which, on some
>   systems (like Unix) is the time of the *last metadata change*, and, on
>   others (like Windows), is **the creation time** for path. The return value
>   is a number giving the number of seconds since the epoch (see the time
>   module). Raise OSError if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.